# Как можно остановить приложение Linux после нажатия Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность

Есть необходимость запустить 2 потока `pthread` для обработки входящих подключений, и обработки сообщений клиентов. Имеется класс `socket`, в нем есть 2 метода `process_connection` и `process_messages`.

Можно ли каким-то образом запустить 2 потока так, что бы при нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, эти 2 потока завершились поочередно и программа могла нормально закрыть сокет и порт?

Пробовал использовать глобальную переменную `is_alive` и крутить цикл в потоке до получения сигнала `SIGINT`, но значение `false` не записалось в данную переменную.

```
#include "include/llenn_socket.hpp"

volatile bool* is_alive;

void process_sigint(int value)
{
    printf("\n[+] The signal SIGINT is intercepted with value %d\n[+] Normal exit from the application.\n", value);
    *is_alive = false;
}

llenn_socket* get_sock(void* data) { return reinterpret_cast<llenn_socket*>(data); }

#define PS get_sock(socket)

void* process_users(void* socket)
{
    while(*is_alive) {
        PS->process_connections();
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    signal(SIGINT, &process_sigint);
    pthread_t thread;

    try {
        llenn_socket socket(4879);
        if (*(is_alive = socket.listen())) {

            if(pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &process_users, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&socket)) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            pthread_detach(thread);
            while (*is_alive)
            {
                socket.process_messages();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &err) {
        perror(err.what());
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("[%u]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

> Добавьте к переменной is_alive атрибут volatile

Такой код не всегда дает закрыть порт.

Comment: Переменная атомарная была?

Comment: @VTT: Нет, не атомарная

Comment: Ну тогда у вас значит было неопределенное поведение - состояние гонки при обращении к переменной из разных потоков без синхронизации. Делайте ее атомарной - тогда должно заработать.

Comment: Добавьте к переменной `is_alive` атрибут `volatile`

Comment: @avp … и так и останетесь с неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT, в моей реальной практике это работало. Думаю у ТС переменная была int (реально с т.з. команд записи в память это atomic), но не volatile и компилятор просто не генерил команду записи в память. (а гонки в такой ситуации можно всерьез  не рассматривать)

Comment: @avp Ну значит у вас было какое-то нестандартное расширение задействовано (например [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/volatile-volatile-keyword-interpretation)). В стандартном C++ одно volatile не избавляет от неопределенного поведения в такой ситуации.

Comment: @VTT, вы о чем? volatile говорит компилятору, что переменную перед использованием надо загружать из памяти, а при изменении писать в нее (из регистра, само собой). Стандартный Линукс всегда работает с кэш-когерентными системами. Далее очевидно.

Comment: @avp [When to use volatile with multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading)

Comment: @VTT, и что? Думает я всю эту нудятину буду читать? Еще раз. Речь в вопросе  не о синхронизации доступа к разделяемому ресурсу, а о чтении измененного в обработчике сигнала (кстати, в общем случае, он может выполнится в любом из потоков) флаге. Без volatile даже однопоточный код такого типа работать не будет

Comment: @avp Да, я расчитываю, что вы прочитаете все ту нудятину. А так как сигнал асинхронный, то, вообще говоря, он будет выполнен вне запущенных потоков.

Comment: @VTT, такого (вне какого-то из потоков) не бывает. Можете попечатать (да, я знаю, что по большому счету печатать из обработчика нельзя, но обычно проскакивает) tread id `pid_t
gettid()
{
  return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}`

Comment: А пробовали нажать Ctrl+z во время работы скрипта? Это приведёт к отправке скрипту SIGSTOP, его останову, и  отдаст обратно консоль. Далее можно разрешить скрипту выполняться в бэкграунде с помощью ``bg %{job_id}``

Comment: @LLENN, а где в приведенном коде вы, собственно, закрываете порт? После обработки SIGINT вы вываливаетесь из циклов в обеих потоках и завершаете всю программу (печатью аргументов). Более я ничего тут не вижу.

Comment: @avp Очень даже бывает. Более того, для обработчика сигнала можно явно задать отдельный стек. Хотя вполне можно говорить об отношении такого сигнала какому-то определенному потоку, например когда один поток блокирует сигнал, а другой ждет. Что касается результатов `gettid`, то эта функция не является async signal safe, соответственно ее использование в обработчике такого сигнала будет не корректно, а собственно возвращаемое значение не особо полезно.

Comment: @VTT, буквоедствуете? getpid является signal safe, думаете syscall(SYS_gettid) принципиально отличается? Кстати, выделение отдельного стека обработчику сигналов никакого отношения к потокам не имеет. Ну, SP в потоке, в контексте которого вызывается обработчик будет установлен на заказанную область памяти. Вот и все.

Comment: @avp Конечно принципиально отличается. `getpid` есть в списке async signal safe функций, а `gettid` / `syscall` - нет.